# Only render shadow of an image with alpha in it (Eevee)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have a plane with a tree texture. The alpha in the image is set as a transparent shader and the black as an emission shader. I want only the shadow of the plane to be in the render, not the actual tree.

The closest I've gotten is getting the plane to dissapear and to cast its own shadow, regardless of the alpha of the image.

I'm also not able to bake the shadow in Cycles because the shadow falls on top of a bunch of hair particles.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the light path node as usual.

Make your transparent material with an image texture controlling the alpha as usual.

In the last step use a *Mix Shader* between your setup and a *Transparent Shader* connect the *Factor* input to the *Is Camera* socket of a *Light Path* node.

[image]